# InDesign: layering options ignored when updating links

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow

#### Question

How to update links when prompted, but also preserve previously selected Layer Import Options from earlier placement?
(linked file has been altered to trigger prompt)

#### Issue Context

Opening an InDesign file with link(s) to Illustrator file that has been modified, and saved, prompts the "update links" or "ignore update links" dialogue.

The INDD has multiple frames linking to separate layers within the AI file. This had been done using Import Options and choosing which layer was displayed (by visibility toggle). The process was repeated for each frame.
The dialogue prompt, after selecting update button, follows with a displayed message stating a change in layer visibility settings will effect linked items.

Then, frames containing links are replaced with the entire art board and all layers. I then have to manually re-link and re-define Layer Import Options for placement of the AI file for each frame.

Comment: Use separate artboards, rather than layers if possible.

Comment: There is another thread that I found - having the equivalent issue with artboards

Comment: I have to agree with Scott, why not work with individual files. You might find your solution eventually but your file might also always cause you that kind of nightmare and you're not working in a "bulletproof" or very quick way in the end. Plus, you'll need to educate any team mate about your way of working. One day, you'll be tired or will do an urgent change, and might update an image without verifying the layer... A bit risky, but it's your choice.

Comment: Fair enough and good points to consider. For the time being I am exporting the layers as individual files. Hoping there is an answer to this - but I am betting on none - need Adobe to make this change!

Comment: I agree with @go-junta. It is way too risky to work with multiple frames linking to separate layers. In theory it seems like a nice tight way to organize your stuff but i have made a mess out of it a couple of times. Adding new layers or renaming old ones. Using the same file so many different places that I forget that they are linked.